# I am confuse , I started my server on port 50001 but my react app is running on 3000 port what is problem ? Plz help me Thanks

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server, node-modules

This is my server mjs file :

```
import Express from "express";
const port = process.env.PORT || 50001;
const app = Express();
import path from 'path'


app.get('/abc',(req,res) => {
    console.log("Resquest ip ",req.ip);
    res.send("Hello World Node js is here");

})

app.get('/application',(req,res) => {
    console.log("Resquest ip ",req.ip);
    res.send("Hello World Node js is here");

})

app.get('/kiet',(req,res) => {
    console.log("Resquest ip ",req.ip);
    res.send("Hello World Node js is here");

})

app.get('/computer',(req,res) => {
    console.log("Resquest ip ",req.ip);
    res.send("Hello World Node js is here");

})
const __dirname = path.resolve();
app.use('*',Express.static(path.join(__dirname,'./web/build')))

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log("App listening on port ",port)
})
```

or You can see my running command of node js and React

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfL9D.png)

Plz hepl Thanks:

where is mistake ? help me. THanks

Answer (score 3):

Because those are two separate apps. you are running your express on 50001 and it's fine but react uses react-scripts to serve your react app on localhost and uses 3000 port as the default port.

Comment: but the brother reacts app is in the node js server.

Comment: what do you mean it's in nodejs server?